# error: 'WordCloud' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, pandas, save, word-cloud

> So this is my code and I was wondering how I can save a python generated wordcloud to my normal desktop? I am using the basic save function but as you can see it is not working.

```
import pandas as pd
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/06HAK003/Desktop/Folders/programming/Excel files/DATAFRAME.xlsx")
text = " ".join(cat.split()[0] for cat in df.Car)
def plot_cloud(wordcloud):
    # Set figure size
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
    # Display image
    plt.imshow(wordcloud) 
    # No axis details
    plt.axis("off");
# Generate word cloud
img = WordCloud(width= 3000, height = 2000, background_color='black', colormap='plasma', collocations=False, stopwords = STOPWORDS).generate(text)
plot_cloud(img)

img.save('C:/Users/06HAK003/Desktop/cloud.png')
```

> I am getting this error: 'WordCloud' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: What does `generate` returns? According to the error it returns `WordCloud` instance, and as the error suggests, it doesn't have a `save` attribute.

Comment: yes, so how else can I save my wordcloud?

Comment: A quick google search reveals: `img.to_file("C:/Users/06HAK003/Desktop/cloud.png")`

Comment: thank you it worked! I couldn´t find it on google!

Comment: Np. It's in the tutorial of `wordcloud`: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/wordcloud-python